# GEKKO gives @error: Solution Not Found when constraint has equality

Tags: python, gekko

when I solve the following problem I get: Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=True)



alpha=[6.97, 4.97, 6.55]
beta = [-0.04, -0.11, -0.1]
MP = [2707.2, 2213.3, 1904.1]
Plower = [1700, 1400, 1100]
Pupper = [5000, 5000, 5000]

h= 250 ; b= 150 ; c= 100
T= len(alpha)

D = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0,  integer=False)


m.Maximize( sum(D[t]*(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T)))


m.Equations(D[t]==alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t] for t in range (T))


#bound
m.Equations(P[t]>=  Plower[t]for t in range (T))
m.Equations(P[t]<= Pupper[t] for t in range (T))
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

then, I reformulate the objective function as m.Maximize( sum((alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t])(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T))) and eliminate the constraint and I get the solution. In other words, I replace D[t] using the constraint.

Can you please explain the logic behind the error. Is there any problem with equality constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Solvers can often perform better with simplification of the model. This is an excellent example of a simple reformulation to eliminate variables `D[t]`. Another way to do this in Gekko is to use an Intermediate variable.

```py
D = [m.Intermediate(alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t]) for t in range (T)]
m.Maximize(sum(D[t]*(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T)))
```

There is also the `m.options.REDUCE=3` option that automates the elimination of variables from the model. It analyzes simple equations that can be removed and variable values fixed with a pre-solve before the problem is given to the solver. This option wouldn't help with this model. Here are the three approaches:

**1. Original (Infeasible):**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
alpha=[6.97, 4.97, 6.55]
beta = [-0.04, -0.11, -0.1]
MP = [2707.2, 2213.3, 1904.1]
Plower = [1700, 1400, 1100]
Pupper = [5000, 5000, 5000]
h= 250 ; b= 150 ; c= 100
T= len(alpha)
D = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0,  integer=False)
m.Maximize( sum(D[t]*(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T)))
m.Equations(D[t]==alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t] for t in range (T))
m.Equations(P[t]>=  Plower[t]for t in range (T))
m.Equations(P[t]<= Pupper[t] for t in range (T))
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

**2. Objective Function Substitution (Successful):**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
alpha=[6.97, 4.97, 6.55]
beta = [-0.04, -0.11, -0.1]
MP = [2707.2, 2213.3, 1904.1]
Plower = [1700, 1400, 1100]
Pupper = [5000, 5000, 5000]
h= 250 ; b= 150 ; c= 100
T= len(alpha)
D = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0,  integer=False)
m.Maximize(sum((alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t])*(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T)))
m.Equations(P[t]>=Plower[t] for t in range (T))
m.Equations(P[t]<=Pupper[t] for t in range (T))
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

**3. Intermediate Variable (Successful):**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
alpha=[6.97, 4.97, 6.55]
beta = [-0.04, -0.11, -0.1]
MP = [2707.2, 2213.3, 1904.1]
Plower = [1700, 1400, 1100]
Pupper = [5000, 5000, 5000]
h= 250 ; b= 150 ; c= 100
T= len(alpha)
D = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, T ,lb=-0,  integer=False)
D = [m.Intermediate(alpha[t]+beta[t]*P[t]) for t in range (T)]
m.Maximize(sum(D[t]*(P[t]-MP[t]) for t in range (T)))
m.Equations(P[t]>=Plower[t] for t in range (T))
m.Equations(P[t]<=Pupper[t] for t in range (T))
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

I prefer Intermediate variables because they keep the model easier to read and diagnose than using very long equations or objective function definitions.